# In which table the images are stored?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

In wordpress Media Library where are uploading the images in which table it is storing the it can anyone have the idea in which table is it stored?

Answer (score 5):

it store data in `wp_posts` table and it's `post_type` is `attachment` and `post_mime_type` is like `image/jpeg` or as per the image and image path is stored in `guid`.

it copy image to /wp-content/uploads/current_year/current_month

Comment: This table only provides the link (wp_posts.guid) to the image.

Comment: @Satyendra it's guid not guide.

Comment: If it works for you than please accept this question so that other user can also refer this in future.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, WordPress never stores the images into Database tables.
While, any upload done goes to the following location:
`/wp-content/uploads/2014/06`
where, '2014' is the year and '06' is the month in which upload is done.

Comment: Not physical path in database